# Big-O notation, logs vs exp

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have simplified these functions to the best of my ability.
I know logs are less than exp, but are all exponential functions greater than logs, even if the power is less than 1?

$$n^{1.01} = \Omega(n(\log n)^2) \Rightarrow 
n^{.01} = \Omega((\log n)^2))$$

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Comment: @JeremyUpsal f()≥() in terms of asymptotic growth

Comment: @Bell  Yes, you can divide both sides by $n$.  You should check this from the definition of $\Omega$ though.  It is not hard at all.

Comment: @Dzoooks I am more confused with ^.01 , because it is less than 1, would the function end up growing slower than the (logn)^2

Comment: $n^{.01}$ grows faster than $(\log n)^2$.  Just take logs and compare: $.01 \log n$ versus $2 \log \log n$.

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/